# Как сделать проверку полей после отправки формы а не сразу?

Tags: php, html

Изучаю PhP, решил сделать самую простую, ненавороченную форму регистрации.
Условия поставил себе такие, если в имени больше 10 символов, то имя не корректно.
Если в email нет 2 точек и одного @, то email не корректен.

Всего чего хотел добился, но проблема с If получилась, при обновлении страницы, текст из операторов ветвления, сразу же показывается, и изменяется только в случае если условие верно.
Как можно незамысловата, самым простым для новичков способом сделать так, что бы текст операторов не показывался пока не будет отправлена форма?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала, чтобы никто не ломал глаза о картинки, код надо вставить __текстом__.

Comment: Ляяя, забыл(
Сори

Comment: интересно, почему заголовок вопроса был как сделать форму, а вопрос на самом деле - как узнать что она была отпралена?

Comment: @MrSilentBeast обновил ответ по вашему обновленному вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Сначала делай проверку

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'] { // пришли данные из формы
```

а потом проверяй их.

Зачем в мыле две точки должны быть? Одной достаточно.

UPD: форму отправляй методом POST

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: А если посмотреть внимательно на код в вопросе?

Comment: У него отправка формы через GET запрос

Comment: да, спасибо, не заметил )

Comment: Снова смотри на код и ищи, что ещё ты не заметил, из-за чего твоя проверка никогда не сработает

Comment: @Ипатьев умник иди от сюда ))  Сработает такая проверка. Если поменять на GET и поставить ее первой

Comment: Я понимаю что со зрением не очень, но если кликнуть по картинке, то она станет побольше. Можно будет посмотреть повнимательнее, и понять, в чем ваша общая ошибка.

Answer (score -3):

Наверное, надо, проверить - была ли отправлена форма?

Вообще, формы, которые отправляют какую-либо информацию на сайт, а не запрашивают её с сайта, отправляются методом POST, а не GET.
Поэтому в общем случае проще всего проверить либо `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === POST)`, либо просто `if($_POST)`.

В случае же, когда форма отправлена методом GET, или на странице есть несколько форм, и надо понять, какая именно была отправлена, то имеет смысл проверить наличие одного из полей, например `if (isset($_POST['firstname']))`.

Кроме того надо помнить несколько важных вещей про отправку форм

- если форма была отправлена методом POST, то после успешной обработки всегда обязательно должен быть сделан редирект, с помощью функции `header()`. Можно на ту же самую страницу, или любую другую, но редирект обязателен
- по этой причине обработка формы должна идти в файле ДО вывода формы, а не после

Comment: "должен быть сделан редирект, с помощью функции header()" - дичь. Форма приходит сюда же, если form action=""

Comment: Господи, при чем здесь то куда приходит форма, если речь идет о том  что происходит уже **после её обработки**?

Comment: Нутк, наведите сначала порядок в своих мыслях, прежде чем ими делиться

Comment: согласен, отправка не очень удачное слово, заменил на обработку

Comment: трудно с такими разговаривать. сними корону, всё равно видно, что ты сам её на себя нацепил. послать бы найух, но воспитание не позволяет.

Comment: @DrMcSheen согласен)